# COUNT aggregate not working on DBPedia when issued via Jena

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web, dbpedia

Below is a piece of code I am using for querying the DBPEDIA SPARQL endpoint. The query `select count(?y) where {?x ?y ?z .}` works fine but the below query does not run giving an error on the variable `?count`?

I think the syntax is right, can anyone point out what can be the probable error here ?

```
        int count=0;

        String queryStringNew="select count(distinct ?y) where {?x ?y ?z .}";

        Query query=QueryFactory.create(queryStringNew);

        ARQ.getContext().setTrue(ARQ.useSAX);
        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://DBpedia.org/sparql", query);

        ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();



        while(results.hasNext())
        {
            QuerySolution soln=results.nextSolution();
            //System.out.println(soln.get("?x"));
            count++;
        }
```

Comment: @RobV's answer is right. For future reference.  sparql.orq has a [query validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html).  If you paste in the text `select count(distinct ?y) where {?x ?y ?z .}` there, you'll get the correct error message “Encountered " "count" "count "" at line 1, column 8. Was expecting one of: …”  Even though "[you] think the syntax is right," it's always a good idea to check.  It's also helpful to post the error message you're getting from Jena.  I'd expect that it was probably a parse or syntax error, and was probably on the keyword `count`, not the variable.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your query is not valid SPARQL 1.1

Virtuoso (the software used for DBPedia) is notorious for having a non-standard SPARQL implementation which supports various syntax extensions that are not valid in standard SPARQL.  This is why when you enter the query at the DBPedia endpoint directly yourself it is accepted.

To be valid SPARQL all aggregates (and project expressions) need to be enclosed in brackets and aliased (have an `AS` clause) e.g.

```
SELECT ?y (COUNT(DISTINCT ?y) AS ?count) WHERE { ?x ?y ?z }
```

If you do want to support non-standard SPARQL via Jena you can turn on extended syntax when you parse the query:

```
Query q = QueryFactory.create("SELECT ?y COUNT(DISTINCT ?y) WHERE { ?x ?y ?z }", Syntax.syntaxARQ);
```

Note that even with this turned on there are still lots of non-standard SPARQL syntactic constructs that Virtuoso supports that ARQ will still reject.

However it is better to use standard SPARQL wherever possible as otherwise you tie your queries to a specific implementation and restrict the portability of your queries.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Jena, the correct syntax the query string should be:

`String queryStringNew = "select ?y count(distinct ?y) where {?x ?y ?z .}";`

or

`SELECT ?y (COUNT(?y) as ?yCount)`

Comment: Can you clarify this at all?  I know that some SPARQL engines might not interpret the spec exactly (they might allow some malformed queries), but I'm missing a step in your answer, I think.

Comment: See [@RobV](http://stackoverflow.com/users/107591/robv) answer with the aggregate explanation I was to lazy to type.

Comment: But as I understand it, Jena shouldn't accept `select ?y count(distinct ?y) where {?x ?y ?z .}` either, since `count(...)` shouldn't appear without being `((count(...) as ...)`.  So I don't understand the first code block.

Comment: Good point - I've always used it this way, I assumed it was in the specs somewhere. RobV re-used the same syntax it seems, so maybe he knows why.

Comment: @loopsam He said that `SELECT ?y (COUNT(DISTINCT ?y) AS ?count) …` is valid, standard, and portable SPARQL, but that Jena can also accept `SELECT ?y COUNT(DISTINCT ?y) …` if the extended ARQ syntax is enabled (it's a long code line though, and `Syntax.syntaxARQ` is past the right edge;  I had to scroll to see it).  I think the gist of it was: "either use standard SPARQL or, if OP needs the non-standard syntax, enable non-standard syntax in Jena".